# Server-side caching Azure Blob storage file content

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a Spring Boot web application integrated with an Azure Blob Storage container in which I save image identifiers for entity categories.
Example: Users can be Teachers, Doctors, Engineers, and so on. In my user list dropdown for each of this category I have an image identifier saved in Azure Blob Storage.

Given that this image identifier does not get changed very often I would like to implement a caching mechanism so that I don't download the same image everytime the user uses the dropdown. Is this possible in the Spring Boot application or I must investigate caching on the UI side?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be wise to cache all this in your Spring Boot application, if you're creating the front-end in for example React as you can use the browser/web-app caching to keep the files cached.